# Geometry nodes: set position on global axis instead of local axis

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I offset points using the Set Position node on global/world coordinates, so that they always move the same no matter the object rotation? I tried searching around and only found that you can do it with an external object using the Object Info node, but I don't really understand how to apply that with the Set Position node.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve. I rotated each curve manually inside their own modified node tree copies, but I'd prefer if I could just rotate the object directly for this effect.

[image: Curves]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is to make the reference to an object positioned at the world coordinates, and then you can use the rotation to this object as the rotation base value for the `Vector Rotate` node.

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks! Though I'll have to ask, the linked object in the Object Info node is the same one that owns this node tree? From the screenshot it looks like so, but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: The object referenced in "Object Info" is just a cube, placed at world origin and with no rotation, and the nodetree is applied to the curves.

Comment: Sorry, It just looks a little confusing because I only used cubes in the scene ;-)

Comment: That's alright. I got a bit confused by the node editor breadcrumbs referring to the same cube as the one in Object Info.